# coldfusion : Regex to match words and replace & change link

Tags: java, regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

I have to challenges in regex.

- QUESTION: 1

How can i replace `href="http://myserver.com"` If in my HTML 
**[Click here]**. for example: 
`<a target="_blank" href="http://myserver.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #fff;">Click here</a>`

Replace With

`<a target="_blank" href="##" style="text-decoration: none; color: #fff;">Click here</a>`

- QUESTION: 2

In My HTML i have to search keyword ** ^mytag^ ** and replace with a value.
currently im replacing one by one in loop.

Current Code:
`#replace(MYHTMLcontent,"^mytag^","Name","All")#`

Is there a way if i can search all my html keywords which is in my case something like `^keyword^` and add in add in structure.

Thanks

EDITED: Adding my new code what im working on im stuck if some-one can help me. it is replacing all links in my HTML.

```
 <cffunction name="htmlurl" returntype="any" >
    <cfargument name="aHTMLTemplate" required="yes" type="any" default="">
    <cfargument name="addr" required="yes" type="any" default="http://url.com">  <!--- OR ## --->
    <cfset regex    = createObject("java", "java.util.regex.Pattern").compile('href=\"[^\"]+\"')>
    <cfset result   = createObject("java", "java.lang.StringBuilder").init()>
    <cfset var htmlcont     = arguments.aHTMLTemplate />
    <cfset var toReplaceURL = arguments.avolurladdr />


    <cfset matcher  = regex.matcher(htmlcont)>
    <cfset last     = 0>

    <cfloop condition="matcher.find()">
        <cfset result.append(
            htmlcont.substring(
                last,
                matcher.start()
            )
        )>
     <cfset token = matcher.group(
            javaCast("int", ( matcher.groupCount() gte 1 ? 1 : 0 ))
        )>

            <cfset token = ("<a href='"& toReplaceURL & "'")>

        <cfset result.append(token)>

        <cfset last = matcher.end()>
    </cfloop>
    <cfset result.append(htmlcont.substring(last))>
    <cfset result = result.toString()>
    <cfreturn result>
    </cffunction>
```

Comment: I can't see any question.

Comment: I see two questions. (Seems the post has been edited.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know anything about Coldfusion. But using pure Java, you could do something like this:

**Question 1:**

```
String replaced = "";
if(element.matches("<a [^>]+>Click here</a>") {
  replaced = element.replaceAll("href=\"[^\"]+\"", "href=\"##\"");
}
```

The regex checks, if the given String is a link with Click here. Then, it  replaces everything between "..." of href with ##.

**Question 2:**

```
String replaced = element.replaceAll("\^[^\^]+\^", "NAME");
```

The regex checks, if theres some ^anything^ anywhere and replaces that by NAME. If you're not familiar with regex: the part between [ and ] matches on anything which is not a ^. Looks kinda funny, though.

I hope this answer will help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Function:**

```
    <cffunction name="tmurlReplace" returntype="any" >
<cfargument name="HTMLCont" required="yes" type="any" default="">
    <cfargument name="toreplaceURL" required="no" type="any" default="http://YOurURL.com">
    <cfset var ehtml = arguments.HTMLCont>
    <cfif refind("<a [^>]+>click here</a>",ehtml,1)>
        <cfset ehtml =  REReplace(ehtml, 'href=\"[^\"]+\"', "href='#toReplaceURL#'", "ALL") >
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn ehtml>
    </cffunction>
```

**Function Call:**

```
`tmurlReplace(HTMLCont=MyHTMLCode)`
```

Hope It will help